# How to open "Add Widgets" View From App

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

My App is supported Today Extension,

I want to add a button to my app's settings view, so when the user clicks on it I switch the user to **"Add Widget"** view, i.e this view:

[image]

so the user can add the desired widget.

Is there a way to do that? or it's not possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. The only thing you can do is to tell your users about the widget and possibly how they can add a widget to the today view:

- Goto home screen
- swipe all to the left
- scroll to the bottom
- tap "Edit"
- tap "+" next to my super useful widget.

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks for the answer, but a question please: is there a reference from Apple document that says that's not possible to do that? 
and thank you for the lovely suggestion :)

Comment: Well, usually apple only says what's possible and allowed. But there's no API for such task, so that's why I said it's no possible.

Comment: Has apple not create anything to solve this issue yet?

Comment: @AnaMM: I don't think they ever will. They don't want an app messing up users' widgets. (It's not a bug, it's a feature).

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no API to display Widgets Edit Screen, because:
Normally there is an "Add Widget" button in app's setting view by default (if widget is not installed yet). So you don't need to open widgets edit screen.
Here is screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just swipe down to open notification center and add your widget as shown in below sample.

[image: Sample]

Comment: I mean how to do that "programmatically" :| :| :| :| @_@

Comment: You have to manually add widgets to your widget list because for now apple never provide any public api to do this thing.